# Which version of Android Studio should I use?

Tags: android

it's a bit that I'm trying to learn Android development but codes from tutorials don't seem to work for me. U have 2.1.2 I guess, I downloaded it from the official site.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? The best answer you'll get is to use the latest version.

Comment: for example, I have never seen until now the usage of basic activities in the beginning,,,I thought there might be buggy versions of android that I shouldn't be using, or that may be a standard one. isn't it hard to keep up with so many changes?

Comment: You don't need the support libraries for the basic Activity class. If a tutorial is using that instead of `AppCompatActivity`, then it's probably focusing on the content of the Activity and logic of the overall app development process, rather than the Support library features

Comment: Maybe you are conflicting the latest "SDK" with the lasted Android Studio version? Those are different things

Answer (score 2):

You have three major options:

1. Use the version of Android Studio that your tutorials use. Ideally, you are using tutorials written using Android Studio 2.x. You can download older versions of Android Studio on [the Android Studio site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable).
2. Use the latest release version of Android Studio (2.1.2). If this is newer than what your tutorials use, you will need to figure out how to do the tutorial steps in the newer Android Studio.
3. Use the latest beta release of Android Studio (2.2). I do not recommend this for newcomers to Android app development.

Comment: Does the IDE version really affect learning about the overall app development process? Android Studio hasn't changed that much, and tutorials mostly provide code, not Android Studio guidance.

Comment: @cricket_007: "tutorials mostly provide code, not Android Studio guidance" -- that depends entirely on the tutorial. "Does the IDE version really affect learning about the overall app development process?" -- for an experienced developer? Probably not. People who have been programming for a while are used to the fact that development tools may differ from written instructions. Newcomers to *programming*, though, will have a more difficult time translating what the tutorial says with what the IDE has. It gets worse if the tutorial is not in the developer's native language. And so on.

Comment: I was mostly curious, say, one used a beta vs stable release? Or used Intellij rather than Android Studio? The IDE itself may "look" different or offer a couple unique feature sets between versions, but the processes of writing the code or running the app doesn't differ that much

Comment: how can I install an older version? I just downloaded it from the site.

Comment: @cricket_007: Again, it is a matter of experience. To you, they are not much different.

Comment: @K.Jor: You would install it the same way that you installed the version that you have. If you downloaded a Windows installer `.exe` file, run it. If you downloaded an OS X `.dmg` file, open it and install the app as normal on OS X. If you downloaded a `.zip` file, unzip it somewhere.